# How do you get github/ios-deploy-master up and running for Cordova CLI?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-3

If you try Cordova CLI's "cordova run ios" command on your PhoneGap project, you'll get an error along with a couple of resources to try in order to set it up for working:

*Error: An error occurred while running the ios project.Error: ios-deploy was not found. Please download, build and install version 1.0.4 or greater from https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy into your path. Or 'npm install -g ios-deploy' using node.js: http://nodejs.org/*

One way is through a GitHub download option. I'm not familiar enough with console syntax to figure out the steps we are expected to follow. To get it working through the GitHub option, I tried following these steps:

1. Go to GitHub and click on the Download ZIP button (at right):
   https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy I used Chrome and unzipped the file by clicking on the name in the lower left of the window.
2. View the folder "ios-deploy-master" in Finder's Downloads folder, and drag it to its final location.
3. To record that location, drag it to the terminal and note what it says. Mine said, /Users/Steve/Documents/PhoneGap_apps/ios-deploy-master
4. We need to add that PATH statement to .profile. Type this in the terminal to check out what paths you have recorded so far:
   sudo pico /etc/paths
5. You’ll see a listing of paths. Copy/paste the path to your /ios-deploy-master folder to the top and press Return so it's on its own line.
6. The bottom of the screen tells us how to exit the page: Control-X, then Y for yes to save, then hitting Return returns us to the terminal.
7. Now cd to the app's folder, then build the app with:
   cordova build
8. Copy the .app file created in platforms/ios/build/device/include/ to ios-deploy-master and run: ios-deploy -d -v RC10ClassicEssentials.app

This command does not run. I don't know what step is wrong or missing to make this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The creator of the code answered:

After you do step 3, in that same Terminal window, run "Make."

This will create an "ios-deploy" executable in the same the folder.